# How do I resample audio to the original stream sample rate in a filter?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, resampling

I have an audio *filter_complex* in `ffmpeg` (*4.3.2-2021-02-27-full_build-www.gyan.dev*, Windows) along these lines:

```
[0:a]a_bunch;of_filters;that_end_up;resampling_the_audio;aresample=????[a]
```

That is, there's a number of filters that end up upsampling the input audio to some other sample rate, and I want to resample the audio back to the original "0:a" input sample rate. However, I don't know what the input sample rate is or what the result of the filters will be, so I can't hard code a sample rate.

Is it possible to resample the audio back to whatever arbitrary sample rate "0:a" used? I don't know how to access that value at the end of the filter chain, and so I'm not sure what rate to pass to `aresample`. Effectively I want to write:

```
[originalA] ... ; aresample= <the rate of originalA> [outputA]
```

I hope that made sense.

Comment: You have to parse it beforehand and substitute it in your last aresample.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks; I figured it was something like that; I'm having trouble finding docs for things like variables and expressions though. I can work it out if I have some docs in front of me. Is there a ... "parse and store as a variable" filter? Or... some metadata thing? I think the only thing I'm missing is a section of the manual that I haven't found yet; I think my search keywords are too vague. I'll keep hunting. Is sample rate a stream level value or is it packet level? I do know the inputs are constant sample rate, at least.

Comment: @Gyan Oh wait, or do you mean; parse it as a completely separate step like with ffprobe or something then pop it into the command line?

Comment: Yes, use ffprobe, extract, and substitute in shell or similar.

Comment: @JasonC `ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp4
`

Comment: Awesome thanks guys.

Comment: @llogan Ah I was struggling a bit, but it turned out I thought I also needed `-show_streams` even though I didn't, and that was causing a bunch of issues.